cursor not showing up properly
in html im trying to change the cursor on my site but its not showing up could i get some help. the cursor im trying to change it to is:

(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAFQklEQVRYCe2XW2wUVRjH/3u/lZZuWxEEW2kJVyumJUYexAupiRgiYlIl8fKKEiMxsQnKC28mXghGCVVo0ojXBwQaJcHEG1i1LYsoS1tuDV0ohd3t7rYz58zMmXPMme6ks1LJFgpPTvLPTnZ39vud//ed73wL/H9NOBAYHh7eaBjG99FotHTi7dt3V8057zIMQ2ia1rdp06Y5AFy3LzzwAOf8sK5rQlVVQYg61NrauhSA+3ZBrGKMHdZ1XWSzWUu5XC5z4MCBVQA8twqiYHVCCOJ2y7cEdF2DptGylSsfPHTkyE/rAfhuBUQBAOdc55wjEAhA13VLmqYFa+fX7Y3FYi8D8E83hBNAANCFEHC5XPB4PNIBS4QS78yZpe/H4/FtAILTCeEEAOecSADOBUoiJTB0AxqllighLhd4S19vbyuA8HRBOAEEY4wLCEgI6UBpaSkopQVS1bHn+06d3A+gZDognADSgTEhEQQHM00QSkCoCqqRAqUz6dUnThz/taGhofJmIZwA0gG3XP24OGbdcSfa23bnU0BByYRSyav37tz54bHNmzfPv5mGVQBgGMaoXL0NYZomZs+egyvDw6CUXKNU8sq8dU+t6dqxY8eKG+0VBQCMMSGDyyKUr8xkeHLtOmx/721IGELUa5RMJqN1tTU/tLe3PQ7AO9WUFABQqmq2/bYLtXUL4PX60N/XC0LIpBoZSYVDQf83X32+98Wp9gonANc0Q1pgrV42JJkOw9Cxbn0z2nbvQjgSvsYB25VsNuNTNWXXvn1fvwEgUKwTTgBBKTXHA9sQ4+l4Ys1a6/d+7+yErumghEyqsVzOc+ni4LYvPvt0S7ENywnACSH5RjRRiBJoZnk55s2rxrcd+zH37mqolPynFFVxJS4ObC0rK7urGBecAIIQ4vp3CmQauGni2Q0vWKn5ruMgli6pt7vjpE6EwuFUNputKmZ7OgF4Mpmkzm1oNSUuwIXAwsXL4PV6ceZMP3z+EOrrG6wOOd6sZMOakM8X+CtfjPJ8ue7lBDDlVrO2oCxAzq3A9q4IBPxo3vASLg9dxN723VAJxX3LG2FoOjRCCtTff7oXgHrdyPkPnQB8cHDQkAHliu3A8p6b3OoDcjvOmFEKwzDw0QfvYOjSJdQvbwRjsm1TS4bBRGvrnssArk4VQDpgNSIr7xIify6Y0g0uoCgqRkdzSKdTyIykEQz6cfxYD6pr6mAyExoliFZWDOVyuZM3AsATiQSXs4Ad2C5ICSSnU7fHhfXPNFsOhCMl8tzEwkUL0Hn0R2t7yhnW7/P/mQ9OpuoAi8fjmgVgNyN5LlgNScDldiGdSuPhR1dj4yuvIhwKwWQMhsHwyGNNKI9WYfHS+0nnb12nAOSsua4IAmcNaD09PUG3252ZqAG7Fsbng5GRDBhjKI+W47XXW6y6kIXLmIF75tewWCy2p6Pj0FkAw0XEtr7iBBhVFEVrbFzxXDgc2RIKhYfkgGrBcA6vxwNFVUCpJucGhCMRhEJhC0hCuT3u9Lkz5xQARwGkigVwnl7y4VMDAwNPV1ZWLolEIm9euHDBQ4j6lmHo1abJ8weRCp9/fECurKpCJptGKBiJt7RsPaEoys8AzsvZ8kYAGABp35cAlimKsqKioqIWwPbu7u4xr9f7rjKm/KFr+kOCc78ASEnJjLOn+8/3fvxJm4SXY1o3AHlf9DXZXy+ZlggA+ddsIYAGAIsAmABqmpqazicSiVA8Ho8CuAIgBuAXAH8DyBZbfDbhZADOz+T0OwvA3PwQKlMmh1EJkwaQyRecLDrNfnAqr/8A7qzs+X+0h68AAAAASUVORK5CYII=)

I have tried a few different things to get it to work but it still hasn't shown up on the site. This is how I currently have it:
html {
  cursor: url('data:image/png;base64,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),auto!important;
}


I noticed in your code there was a typo. I removed the starting quotation mark and it worked. Please note that the background color, height and width were just for demo purposes.


html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAFQklEQVRYCe2XW2wUVRjH/3u/lZZuWxEEW2kJVyumJUYexAupiRgiYlIl8fKKEiMxsQnKC28mXghGCVVo0ojXBwQaJcHEG1i1LYsoS1tuDV0ohd3t7rYz58zMmXPMme6ks1LJFgpPTvLPTnZ39vud//ed73wL/H9NOBAYHh7eaBjG99FotHTi7dt3V8057zIMQ2ia1rdp06Y5AFy3LzzwAOf8sK5rQlVVQYg61NrauhSA+3ZBrGKMHdZ1XWSzWUu5XC5z4MCBVQA8twqiYHVCCOJ2y7cEdF2DptGylSsfPHTkyE/rAfhuBUQBAOdc55wjEAhA13VLmqYFa+fX7Y3FYi8D8E83hBNAANCFEHC5XPB4PNIBS4QS78yZpe/H4/FtAILTCeEEAOecSADOBUoiJTB0AxqllighLhd4S19vbyuA8HRBOAEEY4wLCEgI6UBpaSkopQVS1bHn+06d3A+gZDognADSgTEhEQQHM00QSkCoCqqRAqUz6dUnThz/taGhofJmIZwA0gG3XP24OGbdcSfa23bnU0BByYRSyav37tz54bHNmzfPv5mGVQBgGMaoXL0NYZomZs+egyvDw6CUXKNU8sq8dU+t6dqxY8eKG+0VBQCMMSGDyyKUr8xkeHLtOmx/721IGELUa5RMJqN1tTU/tLe3PQ7AO9WUFABQqmq2/bYLtXUL4PX60N/XC0LIpBoZSYVDQf83X32+98Wp9gonANc0Q1pgrV42JJkOw9Cxbn0z2nbvQjgSvsYB25VsNuNTNWXXvn1fvwEgUKwTTgBBKTXHA9sQ4+l4Ys1a6/d+7+yErumghEyqsVzOc+ni4LYvPvt0S7ENywnACSH5RjRRiBJoZnk55s2rxrcd+zH37mqolPynFFVxJS4ObC0rK7urGBecAIIQ4vp3CmQauGni2Q0vWKn5ruMgli6pt7vjpE6EwuFUNputKmZ7OgF4Mpmkzm1oNSUuwIXAwsXL4PV6ceZMP3z+EOrrG6wOOd6sZMOakM8X+CtfjPJ8ue7lBDDlVrO2oCxAzq3A9q4IBPxo3vASLg9dxN723VAJxX3LG2FoOjRCCtTff7oXgHrdyPkPnQB8cHDQkAHliu3A8p6b3OoDcjvOmFEKwzDw0QfvYOjSJdQvbwRjsm1TS4bBRGvrnssArk4VQDpgNSIr7xIify6Y0g0uoCgqRkdzSKdTyIykEQz6cfxYD6pr6mAyExoliFZWDOVyuZM3AsATiQSXs4Ad2C5ICSSnU7fHhfXPNFsOhCMl8tzEwkUL0Hn0R2t7yhnW7/P/mQ9OpuoAi8fjmgVgNyN5LlgNScDldiGdSuPhR1dj4yuvIhwKwWQMhsHwyGNNKI9WYfHS+0nnb12nAOSsua4IAmcNaD09PUG3252ZqAG7Fsbng5GRDBhjKI+W47XXW6y6kIXLmIF75tewWCy2p6Pj0FkAw0XEtr7iBBhVFEVrbFzxXDgc2RIKhYfkgGrBcA6vxwNFVUCpJucGhCMRhEJhC0hCuT3u9Lkz5xQARwGkigVwnl7y4VMDAwNPV1ZWLolEIm9euHDBQ4j6lmHo1abJ8weRCp9/fECurKpCJptGKBiJt7RsPaEoys8AzsvZ8kYAGABp35cAlimKsqKioqIWwPbu7u4xr9f7rjKm/KFr+kOCc78ASEnJjLOn+8/3fvxJm4SXY1o3AHlf9DXZXy+ZlggA+ddsIYAGAIsAmABqmpqazicSiVA8Ho8CuAIgBuAXAH8DyBZbfDbhZADOz+T0OwvA3PwQKlMmh1EJkwaQyRecLDrNfnAqr/8A7qzs+X+0h68AAAAASUVORK5CYII=), auto !important;
}
<html>

</html>



